# How do I ensure I always get the right base path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Sometimes my basepath i

http://localhost/mywebsite/controller/index

sometimes it is

http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/index

how can I always get the right basepath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Url.Action("Index","Controller")

In order to point properly to your Content folder, you do @Url.Content("~/Content/blah")